# What if one chos vishalom accidentally kills someone right before techias hameisim?

Tags: halacha-theory, rambam, city-of-refuge

B"H

The Rambam in Hilchos rotzeiach 7:9-12 discuss how one who accidentally kills someone and is exiled to a city of refuge never leaves, until the Kohen Gadol passes away.

The question is, what if hypothetically one is exiled to the city of refuge, then Moshiach comes and techias hameisim happens (according to the Ramban who holds it will be forever), and everyone is granted eternal life (assuming that those already alive will simply continue living forever at the time of the resurrection), is there any way for him to leave, since the Kohen Gadol will be alive forever?

On the other hand, since all of Yisroel have a share in the world to come (--resurrection-see metartenura beginning of cheilek), then seemingly even the yid this killed will be resurrected, so maybe that itself will atone for the crime, and thus he would be allowed to leave?

Or maybe even then it's just a gezieras hakasoov that he has to stay the entire time the Kohen Gadol is alive, so would he stay there forever?

Comment: Doesn't everyone die right before techiyas hameisim?

Comment: @sam there was a dayuh somewhere that says that it doesn't have to be that way (and the question is asking according to it), I guess i should find it eventually

Comment: May we have such problems immediately

Comment: I had heard that the person who kills by accident is a way for Hashem to bring someone else to justice who could not be punished by the human court. So maybe by that point, no one will need that kind of justice so it can't happen.

Comment: @rosends hi. Interesting but does that explain the reasoning for the exile in the city of refuge, or just the act itself?

Comment: I think for the act. But without the act, there won't be any need for the exile.

Comment: @rosend this is asking about after the act was done and after the exile started, will the exile stop at techias hameisim, once even the person he killed will be resurrected? This would also raise the question of how the mitzvah of goal hadam could be performed after techiyas hameisim

Comment: In theoretical response, don't lose any sleep over it. If you check the meaning related to "forever", meaning until the passing of the Kohen Gadol, it relates this to the cycle of Yovel. It means until the Yovel cycle is completed, meaning 50 years or less.

Comment: @YaacovDeane interesting! do u have the source for that? I would like to see it. Is it at the start of the yovel, even if the incident happened 1 year before (meaning, when the yovel occurs relative to whenever it happened), or is it 50 years from the incident no matter what?